# Cannot compile code that uses std::io - There is no `File` in `std::io`

Tags: rust

I am pretty new to Rust, and I was just trying to get familiar with the io library by performing a basic line-by-line read from a text file. The example I was trying to compile was straight from the website.

```rust
use std::io::BufferedReader;
use std::io::File;

fn main() {
    let path = Path::new("file_test.txt");
    let mut file = BufferedReader::new(File::open(&path));
    for line in file.lines() {
        print!("{}", line.unwrap());
    }
}
```

When I tried to compile it with rustc, these are the errors I received:

```
io_test.rs:1:5: 1:28 error: unresolved import `std::io::BufferedReader`. There is no `BufferedReader` in `std::io`
io_test.rs:1 use std::io::BufferedReader;
                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
io_test.rs:2:5: 2:18 error: unresolved import `std::io::File`. There is no `File` in `std::io`
io_test.rs:2 use std::io::File;
                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
error: aborting due to 2 previous errors
```

I am using Ubuntu 14.04, and I have no idea if that's part of the problem. I really appreciate any help. Perhaps its just some simple error or mistake on my part.

Comment: That’s code from some time ago. `std::io` has been rewritten since then.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Some things to note:

- `BufferedReader` doesn't exist, there is only `BufReader`.
- `std::io::File` is actually [`std::fs::File`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/struct.File.html).
- `Path` import is missing.
- Opening `File` can fail with error and has to be handled or unwrapped. In a small script `unwrap` is fine, but it means if the file is missing your program aborts.
- Reading lines, isn't a mutable operation, so compiler will warn you of it being needlessly mutable.
- To use `lines` you need to import `use std::io::File`.

Finished code:

```
  use std::io::{BufReader,BufRead};
  use std::fs::File;
  use std::path::Path;

  fn main() {
      let path = Path::new("file_test.txt");
      let file = BufReader::new(File::open(&path).unwrap());
      for line in file.lines() {
          print!("{}", line.unwrap());
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

In addition to what llogiq said

- `use std::io::BufferedReader` => `use std::io::{BufReader, BufRead}`
- `use std::io::File` => `use std::fs::File`
- [`File::open`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/fs/struct.File.html#method.open) returns a `Result` so you probably need to `unwrap` it for instance

[playpen link](http://is.gd/2AUQC6) ... which panics because it `unwrap`s on unknown file

Comment: Oops Daniel was faster and his answer is more detailed than mine

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to import `std::fs::File` and `std::io::BufReader` (You'll also need to change `BufferedReader` to `BufReader` in your code).